# Calculadora Tailwinds css

Tags: reactjs, tailwind

quisiera preguntar si alguien me puede ayudar con un codigo. Estoy haciendo una calculadora con tailwind css y react (solo por practicar) para no agregar 15 botones aprox, cree un arreglo con objetos, y asi crear un solo boton y al recorrer con map() crear los demas botones, el problema es que me crea todo bien pero no logro acomodarlos jaja, al colocarlos quedan todos en linea (flex) y si le quito el flex quedan en una lista.. paso el codigo y si alguien me ayuda feliz.. Gracias.

```
    <div className="flex items-stretch bg-slate-500 h-24">
    <div className="flex-1 justify-center flex items-center">
    {botones.map((boton) => (
      <div className="m-1 flex items-center justify-center">
           <button className="flex items-center justify-center w-20 h-20 rounded-xl bg-yellow- 
      600 m-2 shadow-[0px_10px_1px_rgba(221,_221,_221,_1),_0_10px_20px_rgba(204,_204,_204,_1)] 
      hover:scale-110 active:scale-50 duration-500 ease-in-out hover:bg-yellow-400">
            {boton.operador}
            {boton.id}
            {boton.igual}
          </button>
      </div>
        ))}

     </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Podrias probar con `grid`. Creo que para ordenar botones como en tu caso es mejor porque deja fija la posicion de cada uno.

Comment: @eventHandler Muchas gracias!!! quedo ok ..